how is the feature mapping for the kernel trick "found"?
I did not find detailed explanations for this on wikipedia or other sites.
When I have a dataset that is not linearly separable and apply the "kernel trick" - how do I know if a mapping to the highdimensional feature space is a good separator? If it is - finding both eigenvalues and eigenfunctions and choosing the kernel function values for all data point pairs is sometimes very costly right? How do I choose the kernel function?
Thanks!


how do I know if a mapping to the highdimensional feature space is a good separator?

This is usually done via cross-validation, where you fit a model on training data and then evaluate its performance on a validation set.

[...] choosing the kernel function values for all data point pairs is sometimes very costly right?

Yes, kernalised SVMs are computationally-intensive for datasets larger than a few tens of thousands of samples. You could work with just a subset of the data - use stratified sampling to sample a smaller, but nonetheless representative, subset of the data. Use that smaller dataset for the hyperparameter search. Try limiting it to around 10K samples, and if that takes too long, you can use fewer samples.
At the end, the final model will be fit on all of the training data.

How do I choose the kernel function?

The space of kernel configurations can be sampled randomly or via grid search in order to find a configuration that works adequately well. Rather than searching over too many configurations, I'd initially just try LinearSVC(C=...) at a few different levels of regularisation C=.
If performance isn't good enough, try SVC(kernel="rbf", gamma=..., C=...). It takes a gamma= parameter that you can tune, where larger gamma results in a more expressive model.
For large and complex datasets, RandomForestClassifier and neural networks (e.g. MLPClassifier) are also worth considering.

thanks a lot for your elaborate answer!

My pleasure @peterparker, glad it was helpful.
